# How to use iloc to get reference from the rows above

Tags: python, spyder

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
print(df)
Out[1]: 
    Numbers
0         0
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         1
5         0
6         0
7         1
8         0
9         1
10        1
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
print(dfo)
Out[2]: 
    Numbers
0         0
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
5         0
6         0
7         1
8         0
9         1
10        2
```

The solution to this,I thought, it could be an iloc with 2 ifs:
Check if the digit in df is 1, if1 true then check if2 the i-1 is 1, if true then in dfo see the value of i-1 and add 1,elifs just put the value of 0 in dfo.

I've tryed this:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
# initialize list elements
list = [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['Numbers'])

# print dataframe.
df

data1c = df.copy()

for j in df:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, j] == 1:
            if df.loc[i-1, j] == 1:
                data1c.loc[i, j] = data1c.loc[i-1, j]+1
            elif df.loc[i-1, j] == 0:
                data1c.loc[i, j] = 1
            
            
        elif df.loc[i, j] == 0:
            data1c.loc[i, j] = 0

print(data1c)
    Numbers
0         0
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
5         0
6         0
7         1
8         0
9         1
10        2
```

and for a dataframe of 1 column it works, but when I've tryed with a dataframe with 2 columns :

```
input = {'A': [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
         'B':  [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(input)

# Print the output.
df

data2c = df.copy()

for j in dfo:
    for i in range(len(dfo)):
        if dfo.loc[i, j] == 1:
            if dfo.loc[i-1, j] == 1:
                data2c.loc[i, j] = data2c.loc[i-1, j]+1
            elif dfo.loc[i-1, j] == 0:
                data2c.loc[i, j] = 1
        elif dfo.loc[i, j] == 0:
            data2c.loc[i, j] = 0
```

I get :

```
File "C:\Users\talls\.conda\envs\Spyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 393, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: -1
```

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?
or
Is there another way to get my desired out put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the answer to the question "How to use iloc to get reference from the rows above?", but it is the answer to your proposed question.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1], columns=['Numbers'])
df['tmp'] = (~(df['Numbers'] == df['Numbers'].shift(1))).cumsum()
df['new'] = df.groupby('tmp')['Numbers'].cumsum()
print(df['new'])
```

```
    Numbers  tmp  new
0         0    1    0
1         1    2    1
2         1    2    2
3         1    2    3
4         1    2    4
5         0    3    0
6         0    3    0
7         1    4    1
8         0    5    0
9         1    6    1
10        1    6    2
```

How does this work? The inner part `~(df['Numbers'] == df['Numbers'].shift(1))` checks whether the previous line is the same as the current line. For the first line, this works perfectly as well, because a number and a `NaN` always compare to `False`. Then I negate it mark the start of each new sequence with a `True`. When I then do a cumulative sum, I "group" all values with the created `tmp` column and do a cumulative sum over it to get the required answer in the `new` column.

For the two columned version, you'd do exactly the same... for both columns A and B:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(input)
df['tmp'] = (~(df['A'] == df['A'].shift(1))).cumsum()
df['newA'] = df.groupby('tmp')['A'].cumsum()
#Just reusing column tmp
df['tmp'] = (~(df['B'] == df['B'].shift(1))).cumsum()
df['newB'] = df.groupby('tmp')['B'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

```
    A  B  tmp  newA  newB
0   0  1    1     0     1
1   1  1    1     1     2
2   1  0    2     2     0
3   1  0    2     3     0
4   1  1    3     4     1
5   0  1    3     0     2
6   0  1    3     0     3
7   1  0    4     1     0
8   0  0    4     0     0
9   1  1    5     1     1
10  1  0    6     2     0
11  0  1    7     0     1
12  1  1    7     1     2
13  1  0    8     2     0
```

Comment: The thing is that my dataframe is around 60000 rows x 20 columns. This is the reason why I wanted to get it done with 2 ifs and elifs. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Fair enough, but 6x10^4 rows is easy-peasy for this method. Regarding the if-else, you need to wrap around "safeguards" in it for when `i == 0`.

Comment: Additionally, I think the method I lay out might actually be faster than going through a DataFrame line by line, because it uses all `pandas` internals, which might have optimisations for memory/speed due to vectorisations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you originally proposed. (I mentioned it in a comment already.) You need to put in a safeguard against i == 0. You can do that two ways:

```py
for j in dfo:
    for i in range(len(dfo)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        elif dfo.loc[i, j] == 1:
            if dfo.loc[i-1, j] == 1:
                data2c.loc[i, j] = data2c.loc[i-1, j]+1
            elif dfo.loc[i-1, j] == 0:
                data2c.loc[i, j] = 1
        elif dfo.loc[i, j] == 0:
            data2c.loc[i, j] = 0
```

or start at 1 instead of 0:

```py
for j in dfo:
    for i in range(1,len(dfo)):
        if dfo.loc[i, j] == 1:
            if dfo.loc[i-1, j] == 1:
                data2c.loc[i, j] = data2c.loc[i-1, j]+1
            elif dfo.loc[i-1, j] == 0:
                data2c.loc[i, j] = 1
        elif dfo.loc[i, j] == 0:
            data2c.loc[i, j] = 0
```

The resulting dataframe:

```
    A  B
0   0  1
1   1  2
2   2  0
3   3  0
4   4  1
5   0  2
6   0  3
7   1  0
8   0  0
9   1  1
10  2  0
11  0  1
12  1  2
13  2  0
```